# 4k Laptop with 1920x1080 external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dell, display-resolution

I just bought a Dell XPS Developer Edition 13 inch.  It's awesome, and I love it.  However, I experienced the same problems as others when I plugged in my two external monitors that are both 1920x1080.  Now I have a tiny workspace on the external monitors, with giant font.

I've seen solutions for this on Gnome, but I haven't tested them because I don't have Gnome.  Is there anything I can do on Unity to make this tolerable?

Ubuntu 16.04
Dell XPS 13, Developer Edition
Asus 1080p Monitors

Comment: The way the monitors are set will limit the options but generally you would go the Settings > Screens and change the scale.

Comment: So, when I change the scale, the laptop screen resolution goes way down, as expected, and I have the same problem on the other two monitors.  It doesn't appear to be working as I expected.

Comment: *The way the monitors are set will limit the options*, both for resolution and scaling, i.e., you can only mirror identical displays without issues.

Comment: I know that that's pretty normal.  I'm hoping someone has a solution specific to Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity.  For example, several companies have figured out how to fix this problem, such as Nvidia who has the "monitor scaling", where you can tell it to scale the other monitors...and it works pretty well.  Or the way Apple handles it (I have no idea how they handle it).  I'm hoping there's some software that will at least try to intelligently scale this for me.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but my external monitor is from Dell. There is a similar unsolved question for Windows here: https://superuser.com/q/1202204/455690

Comment: can you at least post a link to the solution for a Gnome system. although I am using Unity, but still Gnome solution might just be helpful, or at least when I shift to Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but the best solution seems to be not to use **Wayland and lower built in display to 1080p**. As Xorg is the default on 18.04 anyway we'll go with that.

1. Connect monitor
2. Lower built in display to 1920x1080
3. Set scaling to 100% on both

Tested on driver nvidia-440

When disconnecting the monitor the resolution will **set the built in display back to 4k** so you shouldn't notice any difference between docked/undocked, except for the obvious loss of quality when watching videos etc (while docked).

This issue doesn't seem to get any better with 19.10 either :(