# Dell XPS 9550 - low resolution on external 4k monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, dell, display-resolution

I have a Dell XPS 9550. It has a 4K screen, which works great on Ubuntu. However, when I plug in an external 4K monitor (specifically, a [Kogan 28" 4K LED Monitor](https://www.kogan.com/au/buy/kogan-28-ultra-hd-4k-led-monitor-ultra-hd/)), the highest resolution available is only 1920x1200. :(

Some info:

- Running Ubuntu 17.10 with kernel 4.10.0-26-generic
- Using HDMI cable that came with monitor
- Using nvidia-375.66 drivers

I tried the steps outlined in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/448113/679041):

```
$ cvt 3840 2160
# 3840x2160 59.98 Hz (CVT 8.29M9) hsync: 134.18 kHz; pclk: 712.75 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-1 3840x2160_60.00
```

However when I try to select 3840x2160, my laptop screen becomes very stretched, and both the external & laptop screen start turning on/off repeatedly.

[image: setting 3850x2160 resolution]

[image: Stretched laptop screen]

Any idea how I can fix this? Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks! :)

Comment: I have a new XPS as well (the one with the high-res touchscreen). I ended up reinstalling with Ubuntu 16.04 instead of 17.10 and using the Nouveau driver to get a stable setup with a standard external monitor.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried switching to the Nouveau drivers and it still does not work. However I am using 17.10 still

Comment: @apostl3pol what is the resolution of your external monitor? could you please explain yourself as an answer here https://askubuntu.com/q/904460/329036 ? maybe your steps can be of some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the laptop's HDMI port, which does not support 4K@60Hz.

However, you can get 4K@60Hz over the USB Type-C port if you use an adapter, such as [the official Dell one](http://accessories.ap.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=au&l=en&s=bsd&cs=aubsd1&sku=470-abql).

I'm not too sure if these work with Linux, however.

Here's some threads online where people discuss the issue:

- http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/xps-9550-trouble-with-external-monitor-4k-60hz.801646/
- http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/xps-15-9550-hdmi-2-0.786509/